# XInclude xml file from resources of dependent java module

Tags: java, xml, saxparser, xinclude

I have a java application that contains of 2 parts: Core project(module) and App project(module). Core module is dependent by several apps. I configure the work of my App module in *config.xml* file. I want to put xml file with common settings to Core module's resources to let all apps use xinclude to include this part to their configs. I use SAXParser to parse *config.xml*.
This is what my *config.xml* looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<myapp>
    <xi:include href="common.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
    <app-specific-data>
    ...
    </app-specific-data>
</myapp>
```

File *common.xml* is places in CoreModule/src/resources. 
How can I access this file from *config.xml* that is places in working directory on AppModule?
Thank you.

Comment: found an answer. posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setXIncludeAware(true);
factory.setNamespaceAware( true );
SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
parser.parse(input, new MyHandler());
```

in your MyHandler class override *resolveEntity(publicId, systemId)* method.
In config change "common.xml" to "cp://common.xml". It will let you get "cp://common.xml" as *systemId* parameter in *resolveEntity()* method.

```
<xi:include href="cp://common.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"/>
```

In *resolveEntity()* method do next:

```
if( systemId.startsWith( "cp://" )  ){
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream( systemId.substring( 5 ) );
    InputSource isource = new InputSource( is );
    isource.setPublicId( publicId );
    isource.setSystemId( systemId );
    return isource;
} else {
    return super.resolveEntity( publicId, systemId );
}
```

If you omit

```
isource.setPublicId( publicId );
isource.setSystemId( systemId );
```

you'll get NPE in *searchforrecursiveincludes()* in *XIncludeHandler*.